# Raspberry discoverable and pairable without pin keep disconnecting

Tags: bluetooth, raspbian-buster

I want to send bytes to my raspberry pi 3 through bluetooth with an application on my smartphone. Bluetoothctl works fine, pairable, discoverable, agent NoInputNoOutput all work. However, my phone manages to connect only for 3 seconds, and then get disconnected for no reason.

[CHG] Device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX Connected: yes

[CHG] Device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX Connected: no

[image: Connected_disconnected]

I run raspbian buster lite, and installed nothing related to bluetooth on it (no conflict with blueman or whatever). Could you please help me ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: I have struggled for over 20 hours on how to connect/pair my 5 or so different brands Bluetooth devices to my three Rpi3B+'s but still found connect/pairing very unstable. You might like search this forum to find how other users finding the same difficulty.  I recently read buster 2019sep26 release notes the following comment: 2019-09-26:
"Latest changes to Bluez ALSA interface integrated to improve connection to Bluetooth audio devices"  So perhaps this new version has some improved performance.

Answer (score 2):

Finally found a way. `rfcomm watch hci0` allowed me to keep the connection and send data through my app.